# Aligning, floating and centering images responsively

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-float, alignment

I'm trying to figure out how to code my HTML & CSS to have the 3 screenshots images align up like in the screenshot below.

The idea is when the user resizes the window smaller the images on the left and right should move in towards the center, or tighter behind the main image and the main image always stays centered.

**My Dev Link:**
http://leongaban.com/portfolio/athenasweb/

**My CodePen**
http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/AwJFt

[image]

And tips or direction would be super appreciated! :D

*HTML*

```
<div class="pattern">

    <div class="athena_thumbs">

        <div class="first">
            <img src="../../images/athena1.jpg"/>
        </div>

        <div class="second">
            <img src="../../images/athena2.jpg"/>
        </div>

        <div class="third">
            <img src="../../images/athena3.jpg"/>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

*CSS*

```
div.inner .pattern {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image:url('http://leongaban.com/images/pattern_diagonal_lines.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    z-index:2;
 }    

.athena_thumbs {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 250px auto 0;
}

.athena_thumbs .first {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    z-index: 3;
}

.athena_thumbs .second {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 10%;
    right: 5%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.athena_thumbs .third {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    right: 10%;
    left: 5%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running late for a meeting.
But, if you take a look at

Code Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bazEr

```
.athena_thumbs {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 5%;  
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.athena_thumbs .first {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 3;
}

.athena_thumbs .second {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.athena_thumbs .third {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I think this will get you going in the correct direction.
There is nothing in the way of cross-browser checking.
Just the basic according effect more or less in place.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you out. I've put together a small demonstration of how I'd go about getting the effect you're after, which you can find [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fPJEB/).

I would set the outside thumbnails to `position: absolute;`, sticking them to either side of the parent container, and ensuring you give them a top position to keep them in line. Set the centered thumbnail to `position: relative`, and center it with automatic margins as you normally would. z-indexing keeps the outside thumbs behind the centered one.